# maven-surefire-plugin converted to gradle for Geb/Spock parallel test execution

Tags: gradle, spock, geb

I found [this page](https://qualityshepherd.com/2014/08/running-geb-tests-in-parallel/) that explains how to run Geb/Spock tests at the method level which is what I would like to do with my tests, but I am using gradle.  Is there a way to convert this to gradle or is it strictly a maven plugin?  I can import the maven-surefire-plugin with gradle just fine, however I can't figure out how to convert the configuration block, or if it is even possible.

I've tried something like below but it doesn't work.

```
tests {
options {
   parallel = "methods"
   forkCount = 4
  }
}
```

I can execute the tests at the class (spec) level by using gradle maxParallelForks property, but I'd like to run parallel at the test level.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to run tests in parallel on the method level depends on what test framework you are using.
As far as I know, only TestNG supports it out of the box.
See here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html#setParallel-java.lang.String-

There is way to make it work independently of the test framework, using only Gradle, but this way you can only do it on the class level.

In your Gradle test task, set the `maxParallelForks` property.

See manual: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:maxParallelForks`